# Delete TFS workspace created by Jenkins / Have same TFS project build on 2 Jenkins servers

Tags: jenkins, tfs, workspace

I have a Jenkins Freestyle project based on TFS.
I now have a second Jenkins server, which also needs access to this repository (different business division).
I get this error on the second server:

```
Mapping '$/MyProject/' to local folder 'C:\JenkinsPathHere\MyProject\' in workspace 'Hudson-MyProject-MASTER'...
FATAL: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreException: The workspace Hudson-MyProject-MASTER;MyName already exists on computer JenkinsServer1.
```

This was the console output when setting up the initial project,

```
Building in workspace C:\JenkinsPathHere\MyProject\
Querying for remote changeset at '$/MyProject/'  
Checking if there exists a mapping for c:\JenkinsPathHere\MyProject...no.
Downloading list of workspaces from http://tfspath:8080/...
Creating workspace 'Hudson-MyProject-MASTER' owned by 'john@shop.com'...
Mapping '$/MyProject/' to local folder 'c:\JenkinsPathHere\MyProject' in workspace 'Hudson-MyProject-MASTER'...
Created workspace 'Hudson-MyProject-MASTER'.
```

My question :

1. Can I have workspaces for MyProject on both servers? If so, how do i do it?
2. If I cannot have workspaces for MyProject on both servers, how do I go about and delete the workspace from Server1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you the exact problem: You're trying to reuse a workspace name. Workspace names must be unique per user. I'm not intimately familiar with Jenkins but I'm sure you can include the agent name or some such in the workspace name.

Comment: Entered someone else's credentials and it worked - it created a different workspace under that person's name.